# How could get Size of element in ArraySeq and also extract 1 by 1 element from it

Tags: scala

I am new in scala. and I want to get below size of element from ArraySeq(Split by comma)

```
ArraySeq(A,B,C,D) // 4
ArraySeq(A,B,C)) // 3
ArraySeq(A,B)) //2
ArraySeq(A,B,C,D,E)) // 5
```

Also I would like to access each element from ArraySeq.

Does anyone can help me out of that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.size` on any of the scala collections.

e.g. `scala ArraySeq(A,B,C,D).size` would return 4

There are a few ways to go about accessing the elements of the sequence

```scala
val example = ArraySeq(1,2,3,4,5)

// Using the apply method 
example(1) // Result 2
example(10) // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown

// Using .get to avoid exceptions
example.get(2) // Result Some(3)
example.get(10) // Result None

// You can transform all elements using map
example.map(_  * 2) // Result ArraySeq(2,4,6,8,10)

// Or do something with all elements
example.foreach(println) // prints 1,2,3,4,5 separated by newlines
```

If you have a nested ArraySeq (i,e, ArraySeq[ArraySet[T]]) you can get the total size using:

```
val exampleNested = ArraySeq(ArraySeq(1,2),ArraySeq(3,4,5), ArraySeq(6,7,8))

exampleNested.map(_.size).sum // Returns total size of 8
```

You can also flatten the nested collections to a single array seq for ease of use with

```scala
exampleNested.flatten // Result ArraySeq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for you comment but my exact scenario is below

1. When I print spark dataframe below
val sms = df2.select("Messages").collectAsList()
then it gives me below result
[
[ArraySeq('A','B','C')],
[ArraySeq('A','B')],
[ArraySeq('A')],
]
2. when I print sms.size then it gives me 3
3. and When I use sms.get(0) then I am getting first arraySeq as below
[ArraySeq('A','B','C')]
but I would like to get total size of every ArraySeq
When I try to get using sms.get(0).size then here it gives me 1 only (not 3)

Can you pls help how I get total size of each ArraySeq?

Comment: @DhrumilShah I've updated my answer to include an example for nested Seqs

Comment: Hi @Alex .... Here I am not getting Structure like ArraySeq(ArraySeq(1,2))...Whatever getting here the structure is like [[ArraySeq('A','B','C')]] instead of ArraySeq(ArraySeq(1,2)) and after using get method (sms.get) it gives me like [ArraySeq('A','B','C')]. and object of this value is (sms.get(0).getClass) "class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema". So here I am not getting an option of .map (sms.get(0).map)